# improve this tikz picture "graphe of |1/x|"

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to write in the left "A" and in the right "B" and delete in axis (1,2,3,..) and just put `$\frac{-\varepsilon}{2}$` and `$\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$`
inter left and right respectively of the `x` axis.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1cm,y=1cm,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-8,
xmax=8,
ymin=-1,
ymax=5,]
\draw[line width=2pt,color=blue,smooth,samples=50,domain=-8:8] plot(\x,{abs(1/(\x))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version that really uses `pgfplots` commands and adds the fills.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump,
x=1cm,y=1cm,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-8,
xmax=8,
ymin=-1,
ymax=5,xtick={-1,1},xticklabels={$\frac{-\varepsilon}{2}$,$\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$},
ytick=\empty]
\addplot[line width=2pt,color=blue,smooth,samples=51,domain=-8:-0.1,name
path=left] {abs(1/x)} node[pos=0.05,above]{$A$};
\addplot[line width=2pt,color=blue,smooth,samples=51,domain=0.1:8,name
path=right] {abs(1/x)} node[pos=0.95,above]{$B$};
\path [name path=aux] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},8) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},8); 
\addplot [pattern=horizontal lines,pattern color=black] 
fill between [of=aux and left,soft clip={domain=-8:0}, ]; 
\addplot [pattern=north east lines,pattern color=black] 
fill between [of=aux and right,soft clip={domain=0:8}, ]; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please I want to write B in above the graphe

Comment: @mamot can I hatch the right part above ? thank you

Comment: the area above the graph @mamot please

Comment: @mamot please what is the use of :\path [name path=aux] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},8) --
         (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},8);

Comment: @Vrouvrou it is an auxiliary path that runs above the visible area from `xmin` to `xmax` , and is being used to define something that can be used with `fillbetween`.

Comment: can I change the color of the hatch ? can I hatch differently by horizontal lines ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou Yes. The hatch color is set through the key `pattern color=cyan` and instead of `north east lines` you can use `horizontal lines`. You can find a survey of the patterns that come with the `pattern` library on p. 666 (!) of the pgfmanual.

Comment: where is the commande to change the position of A and B?

Comment: @Vrouvrou `node[pos=0.05,above]` means at 5% of the path and above.

Comment: @mamot i tryed to hatch the part A, by adding this:\path [name path=aux] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},8) --
         (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},8);
\addplot [pattern= horizontal lines,pattern color=black] fill between [
        of=aux and right,soft clip={domain=0:8},
    ];      but I get errors

Comment: @mamot no I want this for the part of A and let B as before

Comment: in the position of A and B can we write above west ? or above east ? I want to make it more above, because I want to change I want to write in the actual place of B: xy=1

Comment: @Vrouvrou Try `node[pos=0.05,above=6mm]{$A$};` or any distance you like.

Comment: @mamot how we can impose it with arrows.meta ? thank you